# Ambiguous namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

The following implementation is giving the error : "reference to n1 is ambiguous"

```
namespace n1 // (0)
{
    namespace n1
    {
        int x;
    }

    namespace n1
    {
        int y;
    }
}

using namespace n1; // (1)
//using namespace n1::n1; // (2)

int main()
{
    cout << n1::n1::x<<endl;
}
```

By commenting (1) and using (2) the problem is resolved.

Using another namespace in (0) the variants (1) and (2) will work.

Any explanation ?

Comment: just use global prefix `::`. E.g. `::n1::n1`

Comment: What explanation do you need? `using namespace` directives are blunt. You noticed they are blunt, and found the work arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are `using namespace n1;`, the first `n1` in `cout << n1::n1::x<<endl;` doesn't know if it should match on the outer `n1` or the `n1` found in `n1`.